# Async data change when using server side render in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, server-side-rendering

I want to use Vue in **server side rendering**, but the content data inside template have to request from the other CMS server.

```
<template>
  <h1>{{ content.heading }}</h1>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        content: {
          heading: ''
        }
      }
    },
    created() {
      axios
        .get(CONTENT_RESOURCE)
        .then(content => this.content = content);
    }
  }
</script>
```

Due to `axios.get` is an async request, server will send empty content before request complete.

Use curl to request content:

```
curl 'URL';
# It got <h1></h1>,
# but I want <h1>Something here</h1>
```

How do I make sure it can render with CMS content data in server side?

Comment: Does this not work?

Comment: When I use `curl`, it just got `<h1></h1>`, not `<h1>Page Title</h1>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [vue-hackernews-2.0](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0) example, [src/server-entry.js](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0/blob/master/src/server-entry.js) will detect `preFetch` function in current route component.

So, just add a `preFetch` function in current route component and save the data to Vuex store.

```
<template>
  <h1>{{ content.heading }}</h1>
</template>

<script>
  const fetchContent = store => 
    axios
      .get(CONTENT_RESOURCE)
      .then(content => store.dispatch('SAVE_CONTENT', content));

  export default {
    computed: {
      content() {
        return this.$store.YOUR_CONTENT_KEY_NAME
      }
    },
    preFetch: fetchContent,   // For server side render
    beforeCreate() {          // For client side render
      fetchContent(this.$store);
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make following changes in the code:

```
var demo = new Vue({
    el: '#demo',
    data:{
         content : {heading: ""}
    },
    beforeMount() {
      var self = this;
      setTimeout(function(){
          self.content.heading = "HI"
      }, 100)
    }
})
```

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5r9bn4hd/14/).

Comment: That is an ES6 arrow function, no need to create a `self` variable.

Comment: Yes, it definitely works on client side, but I want sever side render.

Comment: And why you make `content` become a global variable?

Comment: Ahh, Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5r9bn4hd/14/) without making it global var.

Comment: @saurabh I think he means server side, it's working only in client side